# Can an iOS app switch the device to silent mode?

Tags: ios, silent

Is there a way to programmatically set the device my app is running on to silent mode? The silence must encompass the entire device, not just my application.

Answer (score 5):

No. As it's a physical hardware switch, there's no software method for muting the entire device.

No reason to fight the framework, just let the user mute the device if he/she pleases.

Comment: Right. And if there's no public API, forget about it. If it's a crucial feature, submit a Radar bug asking for the API to be publicized, but working with the private APIs/method calls is something that you should generally avoid in any production code.

Comment: And when you submit that bug please put it on http://openradar.appspot.com/ so that other developers can duplicate it more easily.

Comment: You are more than welcome to use a private API, as long as you don't wish to distribute via iTunes App Store.  To me, the genius of the iPhone is not just the iPhone/iDevice, but the marketing and distribution channel for apps that builds a suite of value-add businesses on top of it.

Comment: This would be useful when you want to debug an app with audio/video in the simulator without having to mute your entire computer.