# Mute/Silence an iOS device programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, mute, avsystemcontroller

I'm trying to mute the device's ringer from within my app, but for some reason using AVSystemController like in this answer ( [How to disable iOS System Sounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284402/how-to-disable-ios-system-sounds) ) won't let me silence the device ALL the way down.. it drops it to a volume of 1 bar, but not completely silent.

I know it can be done, probably with a private API like AVSystemController, and I know that Apple will still approve the app if the user expects this kind of functionality from the app (since there are already 2 apps I found *in the App Store* which mutes the device programmatically with no need of jailbreaking or anything like that).

Those apps actually do something better - they actually toggle the actual mute, not just decreasing the volume to zero.

Does anyone know the way this is being done?

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: This sounds a lot as if you are attempting something, most users won't like to be done by an App without their consent. I am praying to Steve that this is not doable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828958/can-an-ios-app-switch-the-device-to-silent-mode

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to automatically silence your device when you go into a meeting (plz don't steal the idea). Users will love it, and please don't use Steve's name in vain.

Comment: Hmm, @Roshit , so you're saying I need to submit a request to make that API public? I don't think it's a good idea because it does open the door for mischief, but I believe that Apple WILL approve my app even if it uses a private API... does Anyone have an actual helpful answer please? thanks.

Comment: If you have got any solution than please share it here, so it may help to others also.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, I have a button that toggles sound on and off in a game.  I set the float to 10 when I want sound on and 0 when I want sound off.

```
float value = 0.0f;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareOutputVolume, sizeof(float), &value);
```

**Update:**

Another option that is still working with iOS 9.1

```
float vol = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] outputVolume];
NSLog(@"output volume: %1.2f dB", 20.f*log10f(vol+FLT_MIN));
```

For Swift:

```
let volume = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume   
print("Output volume: \(volume)")
```

Sources for updates answer: [Get System Volume iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7255006/3543861)

Comment: Deprecated in iOS 8x