# Is it possible to turn off the silent mode of an iPhone programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mute/Silence an iOS device programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371312/mute-silence-an-ios-device-programmatically)

Is it possible to turn off the silent mode of an iPhone programmatically?
I need the option to turn on and mostly **off** the silent mode, without using the 
hardware.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of silent mode **not** to be disturbed?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216487/turn-off-device-volume-ios

Comment: Gee I hope not! If I put my phone on silent I don't want some app deciding it's allowed to make noises even though I said silent!

Answer (score 5):

From developer.apple

> Global system volume, including your application's volume, is handled
>   by iPhone OS and is not accessible by applications.

Comment: HOW? There is an app called 'AutoSilent' that put the phone in Silent mode for a specific time and than send it back to Normal mode. How?

Answer (score 0):

No, on iPhone it only on hardware button.

Answer (score 0):

If it were possible, the device would en up in an inconsistent state: the hardware silent-mode button turned on, but in software silent mode is turned off. In short, user experience hell.

Comment: correct you are. but do you know a way to track whether the phone is in silent mode or not programmatically in swift?