# Mute iPhone programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have been able to decrease the volume of Ringer by using `AVSystemController`'s `setVolume` method. However, it doesn't mute the device, there is still 5% volume left. I might need to control the Silent switch but didn't find anything about it.

Please note I don't want answers like The app will be rejected by Apple as I do not intend it to upload.

Comment: Still answers like _the app will be rejected by Apple_ would be a good reference for future programmers with the similar problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can an iOS app switch the device to silent mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828958/can-an-ios-app-switch-the-device-to-silent-mode)

Comment: Didn't find them helpful

Comment: There is an approved application in the appstore.

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/autosilent/id474777148?mt=8

Comment: Hi. I am currently facing the same issue. Were you able to resolve it? Can you share the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It is technically possible to change the system volume through the private `AVSystemController class` in `Celestial.framework`

[Get Framework from here](https://github.com/masbog/PrivateFrameworkHeader-iOS-iPhone-5.-/blob/master/Celestial.framework/AVController.h).

Comment: I have changed the volume but it does not completely mute the ringer. Also used many functions in the framework without much luck.