# Mute IPhone prorammatically is legal?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, volume, mute

I gonna start working on an app that have basic functionality to mute phone(no sound from any app, ring tone).
I searched over net and found some private api's to do what I want.

[Mute iPhone programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096110/mute-iphone-programatically)

https://github.com/forensix/BBSettings

But found some articles saying that Apple will not approve such kind of apps. And when I searched over store I got an app link below

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/autosilent/id474777148?mt=8

This is auto silent app, that put iphone to mute state.

So now I want all my seniors to let me know whether I can do this app or not?

Comment: You should buy the app and see if it works as adversities.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596862/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-mute-the-iphone and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828958/can-an-ios-app-switch-the-device-to-silent-mode

Comment: Everything that mutes the phone programmatically is using private APIs, which is explicitly forbidden by Apple's review guidelines. The app you mentioned probably just slipped through (the review process isn't perfect), but I wouldn't count on that.

Comment: @mayank.karki any luck ? I am stuck in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

The application that you mentioned has the *purpose* of muting the phone. Someone downloading it *expects* it to mute the phone. That's probably why it was accepted on the store.

If your app mutes the phone, and the user didn't expect it, they could very likely miss important phone calls unexpectedly, which could be very damaging. So you would need a very, very good reason to have that functionality in your code.

Comment: My app also has a purpose to mute phone, in fact user will download only because of this functionality. So can I grant this as a approval?