# How to mute/silent device in Xcode 9.1?

Tags: ios, app-store, silent, mute

I uploaded an app on the App Store for students and I would like to add a new feature with an update where it puts the device on mute while the student/user is on class and just after the class it would turn off silent mode.

I researched a lot and some people say that this is not allowed for developers to implement in their apps. Is that true or not?

**Is there a code that puts the device on mute/silent? I haven't seen anything like that.**

Comment: No, only the user can activate do-not-disturb or silent modes

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575073/mute-iphone-prorammatically-is-legal